# How to copy google drive folder and its contents to list of folder ID's

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have a script which loops through entries in a google sheet, creates a folder for each row and lists the id of the folder. I need to be able to loop through the list of folder ID's and copy the contents (and sub contents) of a template master folder into the new folders e.g. ([example here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pH21JtVAXp11bNQth83KD-WGtP4YZ-jD1gFp3Grd7ZM/edit?usp=sharing))

Ive found some examples where you can do this in one instance only by hard coding the target and source folders, but need some help to make it more variable and dynamic.

This is the code I have so far:

```
function folderMaker(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];//get first sheet



  var last = sheet.getLastRow();//end of list size


  //prompt for Folder Name

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var ask = ui.prompt('What is the Main Agent Folder Name? \nAgent folders will go inside this folder.');
  var response = ask.getResponseText();

  //Create a business folder

  var tFolder = DriveApp.createFolder(response);
  var tFolderId = tFolder.getId();//ID to business folder
  var tFolderUrl = tFolder.getUrl();//URL to business folder
  sheet.getRange('A1').setValue('business Folder');//put business folder info in row 1
  sheet.getRange('B1').setValue(response);
  sheet.getRange('C1').setValue(tFolderUrl);
  sheet.getRange('D1').setValue(tFolderId);
  sheet.getRange('E1').setValue(' ');

  //agent folder names

  var ask2 = ui.prompt('agent folder name');
  var response2 = ask2.getResponseText();

  //call the document to be copied


  Logger.log('last '+last);
  for(var i=3;i<last+1;i++){

    var agent = sheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue();//get agent name
    var email = sheet.getRange(i,2).getValue();//get agent email
    var folder = DriveApp.createFolder(agent + ' '+response2);
    var sFolder = folder.getName();
    var sFolderId = folder.getId();
    var sFolderUrl = folder.getUrl();
    folder.addEditor(email);//add agent as an editor of the folder
    sheet.getRange(i,3).setValue(sFolder);
    sheet.getRange(i,4).setValue(sFolderId);
    sheet.getRange(i,5).setValue(sFolderUrl);

    //Add agent folders to business folder
    var businessFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(tFolderId);

    var agentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(sFolderId);

    businessFolder.addFolder(agentFolder);//put agent folder in business folder

    DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFolder(agentFolder);//take agent folder out of Google Drive
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you are trying to iterate through your sheet, create a folder for each row, and copy the contents of a template folder to that new folder. I've written something that should do the trick for you, and I highly recommend that you read through it to see if it does what you are looking for, and how it works.

```
function main () {
  /*
  Get a template folder id from sheet, and copy that template to custom folders and share with a user.
  */
  var ss, sheet, templateFolderId, templateFolder, rootFolder,
      header, range, values, i,
      folderPath, folder
  ;
// Get spreadsheet and sheet
  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

// Get template folder
  templateFolderId = sheet.getRange("C2").getValue();
  templateFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(templateFolderId);

// Get root folder for where the new folders will live/be created
/*
*** Change this location if you nest them somewhere else***
*/
  rootFolder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();

// Get rows to process
  header = sheet.getRange(3,1,1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]; // Get header row
  header = Map(header); // Map header to an object to give column references clarity later
  range = sheet.getRange(4, 1, sheet.getLastRow() -3, sheet.getLastColumn()); // Get range of rows for processing
  values = range.getValues(); // Get data

// Iterate through rows.
  i = values.length;
  while (i--) {
//   Check for missing folder IDs (indicates it hasn't been processed).
    if (! values[i][header["Folder ID"]]) {
//     Split folder name into pieces
      folderPath = values[i][header["Folder Name"]].split("/");
//     Get destination folder
      folder = EnsureFolderExists(folderPath, rootFolder);
//     Copy template to folder
      CopyMasterTemplate(templateFolder, folder);
//     Share folder with user
      folder.addEditor(values[i][header["Email To Share Folder"]]);
//     Save folderId to row
      values[i][header["Folder ID"]] = folder.getId();
      values[i][header["Folder URL"]] = folder.getUrl();
    }
  }

// Save updated values to range
  range.setValues(values);
}

function CopyMasterTemplate (templateFolder, destinationFolder) {
  /*
  Copy contents of templateFolder to folder
  Must be recursive - folders within folders, unknown depth
  */
  var fileIterator, folderIterator, folder
  ;
// Copy files
  fileIterator = templateFolder.getFiles();
  while (fileIterator.hasNext()) {
    fileIterator.next().makeCopy(destinationFolder);
  }
// Copy folders
  folderIterator = templateFolder.getFolders();
  while (folderIterator.hasNext()) {
    folder = folderIterator.next();
    CopyMasterTemplate(folder, destinationFolder.createFolder(folder.getName()));
  }
  return;
}

function EnsureFolderExists (a, within) {
  /*
  Ensure folder path split in array a is available in folder within
  */
  var folder = within,
      folderIterator,
      i = 0
  ;
  while (i +1 <= a.length) {
    folderIterator = folder.getFoldersByName(a[i]);
    if (folderIterator.hasNext()) {
      folder = folderIterator.next();
    }
    else {
      folder = folder.createFolder(a[i]);
    }
    i++;
  }
  return folder;
}
function Map (a) {
  /*
  Map 1d array to object
  */
  var o = {},
      i = a.length
  ;
  while (i--) {
    o[a[i]] = i;
  }
  return o;
}
```

Comment: You are an absolute legend. Ive always struggled a bit with iteration but this sets it out really nicely.

Comment: The code is working great so far with one slight hitch - it only seems to copy of the child folders within the parent (templatefolder) however there are 3 children. Can you assist or point me in the right direct? Appreciate your help so far.

Comment: I believe the issue is due to my neglecting to declare variables in CopyMasterTemplate. I've edited my code above. It should now work to copy more than one folder per level.

Comment: Its throwing an error of "Map undefined" at : header = Map(header);

Comment: I'm not seeing that issue. Is the Map function on the bottom included when you copy the snippet?

Comment: well this is embarrassing. amazing, thank you so much